# Tracking (and deleting) output files from a Gradle task

Tags: gradle, gradle-plugin

With the Google protobuf-gradle-plugin, it generates potentially multiple files based on a number of proto file inputs. When running the task, it's only possible to see all the files that have been output, rather than determine a-priori what the outputs will be.

The challenge comes when it's time to clean the project. It appears that Gradle will track the output files, accessible from `AbstractTask.getOutputs().getPreviousFiles()`. That is Gradle internal, so I doubt you can rely on that. If you wanted to delete all the output files, what is the best way to do this?

1. One possibility is to restrict the output folder to the build directory, so that if it is removed, all generated files will be gone.
2. Another is to create a manifest in the output directory that will track all the created files, then it will know what to delete.

What is suggested here?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on internal API isn't a good idea. It's not internal by accident but may be changed without any notifications, hence spoil the build.

Less error prone and easier to implement is redirecting the output to `project.buildDir`. In this case everything is simple, this folder will be removed on `clean` invocation and files will be erased.

When it comes to creating a manifest I find it harder to implement and maintain as well as more error prone - you need to get to know gradle mechanisms well (which may be not as difficult as it seems) to implement it in the right way. I also don't find any pros for this solution. Do you have any?

So, summing up, change the output folder.

Comment: How to handle the case when outputs are removed? For IncrementalTaskInputs, you might be able to calculate the differences. Otherwise you'll need to always delete the entire output directory and then repopulate the whole lot. Is it possible to do anything better?

Comment: @brunobowden if I understand it well gradle take care of it be default. If you annotate the task outputs gradle will prepare them always when missing.

Comment: You're correct @opal. I didn't explain it well enough. I'm thinking of when an ATinput change results in an AToutput change. Due to limitations for the protobuf plugin, it doesn't know when an edit to an ATinput might cause an AToutput to disappear. In which case, it'll have to clear all the output and then recreate everything.